# substr remove images from post content

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a problem with getting the post content without the images.

I have a code like this:

```
$html="";
 $html .= '<p class="news-text col-xl-12">'. preg_replace('/\s+?(\S+)?$/', '&#133;',
 substr(get_post_field('post_content', $post_id) .'', 0, 250)) .'</p>';
```

I have also tried:

```
substr(strip_tags( get_the_excerpt() ),0,250));
```

but I didn't have any luck with it. Could you please help me out?

Comment: You could try using `strip_tags()` and just pass a list of allowed formatting tags.

Comment: You should be using something like DOMDocument to process HTML rather than hacking it with string manipulation or regex's.

Comment: @Nigel Ren why is this DOMDocument better then string manipulation?

Comment: String manipulation doesn't understand the context of the data.  HTML/XML have a particular structure which is there for a reason and easy to get wrong if you try and do it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think this is ok

```
$content = get_post_field('post_content', $post_id);
$content = preg_replace("/<img[^>]+\>/i", "", $content);
```